How should I make an `u128` addition operation atomic?
Background:
I'm running in a multi-threaded environment where 64 bit values are being added to a global counter (u128) 25-50 times a second.
My Starting Point
I wrote a little snippet:
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AtomicU128 {
    lsv : AtomicU64,
    msv : AtomicU64,
}

impl AtomicU128 { 
    fn fetch_add(&self, value : u64) -> u128 {
        let mut previous = self.lsv.fetch_add(value, Ordering::SeqCst) as u128;
        
        previous += if previous + value as u128 > u64::MAX.into() {
            let x = self.msv.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst);
            x as u128
        } else { 0 };
        
        previous
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a_u128 : AtomicU128 = AtomicU128 { lsv: AtomicU64::new(u64::MAX), msv: AtomicU64::new(0), };
    
    a_u128.fetch_add(1);
    
    println!("{:?}",a_u128);
}

which has a gaping hole in how it's handling the lsv 64bit overflow.
If I wrap the operation in a Mutex, should I bother with the AtomicU64 types?
Edit:
I put the following together, but it feels a little cumbersome:
#[derive(Debug)]
struct AtomicU128 {
    inner: Mutex<u128>,
}

impl AtomicU128 {
    fn new(value: u128) -> Self {
        AtomicU128 {
            inner: Mutex::new(value),
        }
    }

    fn add(&self, value: u128) {
        let mut inner = self.inner.lock().unwrap();
        *inner += value;
    }

    fn get(&self) -> u128 {
        *self.inner.lock().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = AtomicU128::new(u64::MAX.into());
    
    println!("Before {:?}",v.get());
    v.add(1);
    println!("After  {:?}",v.get());
}

Is there a better way to safely add to u128 types together?

No, the entire point of Mutex is that you don't care about atomicity.

Also, if you use Mutex, you can just use u128.

Are you sure your use case requires a real atomic fetch+add?  If the requirements are actually looser, like everyone just has to see it increase monotonically, then you could fulfill that more easily.

@ChayimFriedman I did this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d32cf3bd91dcdd37d8e75e7bdc7de0b3
But it's a little cumbersome.  Can you suggest an improvement?

Why cumbersome? It's very little code and easy to understand.

Being relatively new to Rust, its the .unwrap() s I'm concerned about ... I would like to avoid having code path to a panic!(), and dealing with that seems cumbersome.

@Jamie lock().unwrap() is one of the rare places where you shouldn't care about the unwrap(). The lock will only be None if it is poisoned, which will only happen if a thread panicked while holding it. So this is essentially just propagating the panic that happened in another thread. If you don't like it, you can handle it.

At a rate of 50 operations per second, it will take three years of adding 32-bit values to overflow a 64-bit integer. Maybe you can make do with a 64-bit value?

And that if you always add u32::MAX. If you add random values, statistically it will overflow after 5.5 years.

@SvenMarnach That was an oversight when I edited the question; it's actually a 64 bit value (not a 32bit) that's being added 25-50 times a second.

32 into 96
You can add 32-bit integers into a 96-bit count by splitting the count into overlapping 64-bit ranges:
Let L = count mod 264
Let M = count >> 32 mod 264
Now, when you add x, you atomically add into L, set x = (x>>32) + carry, and atomically add into M.
When you read, you can consider the lower-order word to be "authoritative".  If it doesn't match the overlapping bits in the higher-order word, then the difference between the values will let you deduce the appropriate correction.
64 into 128
If you want to 64-bit addends into a 128-bit count, you can split those addends into upper and lower 32-bit halves.
The upper 32-bit halves can be added into a 96-bit counth, and the lower 32-bit halves can be added into a 96-bit countl.
The total count is then always just (counth<<32) + countl.  Note that observers may not see the two updates to countl and counth as atomic, but they will at least see the total count as monotonically increasing.

This doesn't make it properly atomic, just more rarely wrong. A possible sequence of events: thread A loads L, thread B appends 0x10000000_00000001, thread A loads M and H. Now, thread A result will be value + 0x10000000_00000000, which is neither the previous value nor the current value.

The question says that the values being added are 32 bits.  2 threads would have to be out of sync by at least 2^31 operations before anyone gets a wrong value.  That is not going to happen, since the question also mentions that the rate is 50/s.  A thread would have to be stalled for over a year.

Missed that part in the question. However, I will argue that for a rate of 50ops/sec a Mutex will be fine, and there is no read for this convoluted schema.

That really depends on how often it's read

I thought RwLock read guard is fast, but out of curiosity I benchmarked your solution versus RwLock with threads that only read. Turns out RwLock is 100x slower with one or two threads, and is 300x slower with 8 threads. So there is definitely a place for your solution :) (btw, parking_lot RwLock was slower than std).

@MattTimmermans  Thank you for you response, but I'm sorry: I made a mistake in editing the question: it's u64 value being added at 25-50 Hz, not u32.

@Jamie  Updated to accommodate the new requirement.
